# Applying Matrix Chio's Law

Tags: c#, matrix, determinants

I am trying to apply Chio's law on my program. You may not be familiarized with Chio's Law (or know it by other name), here in Brazil we call it *Lei de Chió* (Chio's Law), I could not find it's english equivalent. Here is how it goes: 
Say we have a matrix [image: a], to get its determinant we isolate both 1 line and column then we do this for every single item that is not isolated: [image], you get the picture, right?

To calculate det(A), we do: [image], where i is the 1's line on the A matrix and j is the 1's column on the A matrix.

My question is, how do I implement it in C#?
Here is my matrix code: [Check it on Github](https://github.com/naccib/matrizes/blob/master/Form1.cs).